# Derivative of $\cos \theta$ using only dot product

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $\cos \theta$ between points $i$, $j$, and $k$ using only the dot product or cosine, but not sine. I have a potential answer (see below) but would like to check my math. I am putting this into a source code, which is not fully working. So, I need to ensure it is not my derivation below that is causing this.

$\cos \theta = \dfrac {r_{ij} \cdot r_{jk}}{\lvert r_{ij}\rvert\lvert r_{jk}\rvert}$

Derivative:

$\dfrac {d}{dx} \cos \theta = \dfrac {\dfrac {dr_{ij}}{dx} \cdot r_{jk}}{\lvert r_{ij}\rvert\lvert r_{jk}\rvert} + \dfrac {r_{ij} \cdot \dfrac {dr_{jk}} {dx}} {\lvert r_{ij} \rvert \lvert r_{jk} \rvert} - \dfrac {r_{ij} \cdot r_{jk}} {\lvert r_{ij} \rvert} \dfrac {d\lvert r_{ij} \rvert} {dx} - \dfrac {r_{ij} \cdot r_{jk}} {\lvert r_{jk} \rvert} \dfrac {d\lvert r_{jk} \rvert} {dx}$.

Rearrange:

$\dfrac {d} {dx} \cos \theta = [(\dfrac {dr_{ij}} {dx} \cdot r_{jk} + r_{ij} \cdot \dfrac {dr_{jk}} {dx}) - \cos \theta (\lvert r_{jk} \rvert \dfrac {d\lvert r_{ij} \rvert} {dx} + \lvert r_{ij} \rvert \dfrac {d\lvert r_{jk} \rvert} {dx})] \dfrac 1 {\lvert r_{ij} \rvert \lvert r_{jk} \rvert}$.

Comment: Your second line is completely mistaken: this is not how one derives denominators.

Comment: It seems I am applying the quotient rule incorrectly. I am working on the fix.

Comment: How about this? I am not sure I am treating the multivariable correctly.  $\dfrac {d}{dx} \cos \theta = \dfrac {\lvert r_{ij}\rvert\lvert r_{jk}\rvert (\dfrac {dr_{ij}}{dx} \cdot r_{jk}+r_{ij} \cdot \dfrac {dr_{jk}} {dx})-r_{ij} \cdot r_{jk}(\dfrac {d\lvert r_{ij}\rvert}{dx}+\dfrac{d\lvert r_{jk}\rvert}{dx})}{\lvert r_{ij}\rvert\lvert r_{jk}\rvert^2+\lvert r_{ij}\rvert^2\lvert r_{jk}\rvert}$

Comment: No, it's impossible to get sums in the denominator.

Comment: I have a more fundamental question: what is this $x$ relative to which you’re taking the derivative?

Comment: $i$, $j$, and $k$ are in a Cartesian coordinate system. So each has an $x$ component.

Comment: So would the bottom just be squared then?